# Defining a new location for syslinux configuration files when setting up PXELinux

Tags: linux, pxe-boot, isc-dhcp, syslinux

I am working on a mock up of a PXE server for the place I work. I am trying to put the image files and configuration file in places that keep things a little more organized. Even though my `dhcpd.conf`specifies the configuration options needed to tell PXELinux where to look for config files it still does not find said files.

Here is what my /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf looks like, this is where I imagine the issue is.

```
option space PXE;
option PXE.mtftp-ip             code 1 = ip-address;
option PXE.mtftp-cport          code 2 = unsigned integer 16;
option PXE.mtftp-sport          code 3 = unsigned integer 16;
option PXE.mtftp-tmout          code 4 = unsigned integer 8;
option PXE.mtftp-delay          code 5 = unsigned integer 8;
option arch                     code 93 = unsigned integer 16;

option space pxelinux;
option pxelinux.magic                   code 208 = string;
option pxelinux.configfile              code 209 = text;
option pxelinux.pathprefix              code 210 = text;
option pxelinux.reboottime              code 211 = unsigned integer 32;

ddns-update-style none;

option domain-name "lab.solignis.com";
option domain-name-servers ns01.lab.solignis.com;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

authoritative;
log-facility local7;

subnet 192.168.147.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 192.168.147.100 192.168.147.254;
        option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
        option routers 192.168.147.2;
        option broadcast-address 192.168.147.255;
        default-lease-time 600;
        max-lease-time 7200;

        class "pxeclients" {

                match if substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 9) = "PXEClient";
                next-server 192.168.147.10;

                if option arch = 00:00 {
                        option pxelinux.configfile "common.cfg";
                        option pxelinux.pathprefix "/configs/";
                        filename "/pxelinux/images/BIOS/pxelinux.0";
                } elsif option arch = 00:06 {
                        #option pathprefix "/configs/";
                        #option configfile "/EFIx64/default";
                        filename "/images/EFIx64/syslinux.efi";
                } elsif option arch = 00:07 {
                        #option pathprefix "/configs/";
                        #option configfile "/EFIx64/default";
                        filename "/images/EFIx64/syslinux.efi";
                } elsif option arch = 00:09 {
                        #option pathprefix "/configs/";
                        #option configfile "/EFIx64/default";
                        filename "/images/EFIia32/syslinux.efi";
                }
        }

}
```

Parts of the config were compiled from various parts of documentation, the parts that are commented out are old pieces that I have not fixed yet disregard those. For now I just want to get standard BIOS working (`arch = 00:00`).

Here is what my file structure looks like for my tftpboot directory.

```
server01@server01:/var/lib/tftpboot$ tree
.
└── pxelinux
    ├── configs
    │   └── common.cfg
    └── images
        ├── BIOS
        │   ├── ldlinux.c32
        │   └── pxelinux.0
        ├── EFIia32
        │   └── syslinux.efi
        └── EFIx64
            └── syslinux.efi

6 directories, 5 files
```

I was pretty sure I have it setup right for pxelinux but it does not see the config file so something is not configured right. Can anyone provide an idea of what I misconfigured? I have been banging my head on this all day.

Comment: Have you made it working? I was constructing similar config, but at the end, I could not get it working with isc-dhcp. The problem was that server was not sending option 209 (config file name), but this is essential for this setup.
This is because client was not explicitly requesing it. I tried to make isc-dhcp to forcibly send it using this https://askubuntu.com/a/969612/795775 method.
And it did not work. Viewing dhcp packats in Wireshark showed that 209 option was not sent.
However, there was no such issue with dnsmasq - it really forcibly sends an option if configured such way in config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the `configfile` is relative to the `pathprefix`:

```
            if option arch = 00:00 {
                    option pxelinux.configfile "common.cfg";
                    option pxelinux.pathprefix "/pxelinux/configs/";
                    filename "/pxelinux/images/BIOS/pxelinux.0";
```

this will look
for a config file called /pxelinux/configs/common.cfg on the TFTP server.

if this fails just get a Wireshark traffic capture and see the TFTP file requests and where they are pointing to.

Comment: Sigh.... I never even thought of using wireshark. Awesome idea I will try that tomorrow.

Comment: Wireshark seems really too much when `grep tftp /var/log/syslog` on the tftp server should be enough to show the requested files. Maybe you need to add `--verbose` to the tftpd options (in `/etc/default/tftpd-hpa` on Debian).

Comment: Wireshark is the ultimate test even if your server does not log a thing...

Answer (score 0):

I fought with this today and finally made it work. The key was this little section in the [PXELINUX wiki](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=PXELINUX) (I had ISC dhcp-4.2.5-79.el7.centos.x86_64 on CentOS 7.8):

*In ISC dhcp versions greater than 3.0, site-local option spaces start at 224, not 128 (to be compliant with RFC 3942), so you should define the PXELINUX options 208-211 as regular DHCP options, rather than site local ones. For example:*

```
 option magic      code 208 = string;
 option configfile code 209 = text;
 option pathprefix code 210 = text;
 option reboottime code 211 = unsigned integer 32;
```

*Inside your PXELINUX-booting group or class (wherever you have the PXELINUX-related options, such as the "filename" option), you would add, for example:*

```
 # Always include the following lines for all PXELINUX clients
 option magic f1:00:74:7e;
 if exists dhcp-parameter-request-list {
  # Always send the PXELINUX options (specified in hexadecimal, ie: 208 = 0xd0, 209 = 0xd1, etc.)
  option dhcp-parameter-request-list = concat(option dhcp-parameter-request-list,d0,d1,d2,d3);
 }
 # These lines should be customized to your setup
 option configfile "configs/common";
 option pathprefix "/tftpboot/pxelinux/files/";
 option reboottime 30;
 filename "/tftpboot/pxelinux/pxelinux.bin";
```